# Encryption Cipher not filling Grid

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, encryption

Okay so i have been working on this project for just educational purposes, not really interested in the security of the cipher. The cipher works by first generating a random grid with a different location for every ascii character (that is stored in the ord function, which is 0-256) and then encrypt a message into coordinates on the grid. The problem is occuring with this code to generate the grid:

```
import random
from pickle import load, dump
class Encryptor():
    def __init__(self):
        #array=[]
        #for i in range(129):
        #    array.append(False)
        array_full=[]
        for i in range(16):
            array_full.append([False]*16)
        self.letterkeys = range(256)
        self.coords=[]
        self.key=False
        self.grid=array_full
    def gen_key(self):#Generate the Key
        prev_grid=self.grid
        full=False
        while not full:
            try:
                coord=(random.randint(0, 16),random.randint(0, 16))
                val=random.choice(self.letterkeys)
                if coord not in self.coords:
                    del self.letterkeys[self.letterkeys.index(val)]
                    self.grid[coord[0]][coord[1]] = val
                    self.coords.append(coord)
            except:
                full=True
        self.key=self.grid
        self.grid=prev_grid
    def dump_key(self,name):
        file=open(name,'w')
        dump(self.key,file)
        file.close()
    def encrypt(self,message):
        pass
encrypt=Encryptor()
encrypt.gen_key()
encrypt.dump_key('example.key')
print encrypt.key
```

The given output should be simply a full grid with no more falses left all ascii codes, but instead i get something like this:

```
[[False, 151, 204, False, 112, 47, 58, False, 123, 126, 255, 111, 133, 39, 15, 14, 188, 88, 242, 241, 114, 195, 117, 105, 106, 25, 70, 187, False#etc.
```

So for some reason the letterkeys are running out before filling the grid, so I beleive it may be an array-size problems. Is this a correct assumption, if not what am i doing wrong?

***PLEASE NOTE:*** I would not like to use any higher level modules like numpy and such things that make life easier, as I wanted this project as a learning experience to develop my knowledge of python.

Comment: You really need to learn about `random.shuffle`.

Comment: really the point of this was to create my own cipher obscurely to learn more about the python language, or else i would just get a cipher module, so I dont plan on using anything more complex, not even numpy

Answer (score 1):

```
class Encryptor():
    def __init__(self):
        array=[]
        for i in range(129):
            array.append(False)
        array_full=[]
        for i in range(129):
            array_full.append(array)
        self.letterkeys = range(257)
        self.grid=array_full
```

Your first loop is building a list of [False, False, False, ...]

Your second loop is *not* building a list of lists like you want it to, it is building a list of *the same list repeating*.

That's not a very clear distinction in text, but look at this:

```
>>> list1 = [False, False]        # Two items in a list
>>> list2 = []                    # An empty list
>>> list2.append(list1)           # Make a 2x2 grid
>>> list2.append(list1) 
>>> list2
[[False, False], [False, False]]  # Looks fine
>>> list1[0] = True               # Change only one thing in list1
>>> list2
[[True, False], [True, False]]    # Oh, two things have changed!
>>>
```

This seems to tie in with your other code, which tries to say:

- Build a grid of 16,000+ squares
- Map 256 letters onto that
- Now the grid should be full

The grid will be nowhere near full. Nowhere near.

But it looks nearly full when you print it, because of the above - when you set one value, it's changing in every copy of the list.

The fact that you randomly choose grid locations to fill is another combined mistake - because you can fill grid[0][1] or grid[1][1] and the values change throughout all the copies, means that your test `if coord not in self.coords:` which is supposed to stop you overwriting the same place twice doesn't actually do that because you end up overwriting the same place twice just using different coordinates.

(Aside, how are you imagining you can map 256 numbers onto a 16,000+ item grid (0-256, 0-256) by only using coordinates for (0-127, 0-127), and have it be full afterwards?)

Notes

- You can generate a list like `[False] * 128`
- If you want to ensure you fill a list, explicitly iterate over it or count through it, don't pick random locations. Worst case it just takes longer, but it's not easy to reason whether it will work at all
- `file` is already a name in Python, it's bad form to use it for the name of your open file
- This kind of comment helps nobody: `def gen_key(self): #Generate the Key`
- Use `import string` and `string.ascii_letters` or `string.printable`
- You are already using the `random` module, `random.shuffle` is made for shuffling lists

**Edit**

Presenting an answer: Throw your code away, you don't need pickle, you don't need a class, you don't need huge lists, you don't need to loop in Python, make use of the module that come with Python, you just need to shuffle 26 letters and some punctuation into a different order and then use it to encode some text:

```
import string, random

plain = string.printable

tmp = list(string.printable)
random.shuffle(tmp)
shuffled = ''.join(tmp)

trans_table = string.maketrans(plain, shuffled)

print string.translate("some text here", trans_table)
```

Comment: very useful thanks but the other answer is actually presenting an answer

Comment: @pianist1119 they are presenting an answer that won't work, and I explained why. Your design isn't fixable, it needs redesigning.

Comment: are you saying that this is impossible or unreasonable? please read the bottom of my post

Comment: im using this for school to demonstrate my knowledge of python so I wanted to use classes, __init__ and such functions, and make it 99% python syntax

Comment: I'm saying it's impossible to map 256 values onto 16,000 cells. That's what you're trying to do you need to decide what to do instead. (I did read the bottom of your post. Where is NumPy mentioned anywhere? What I suggested is a 'pythonic' answer - use the things that come with Python to do what you want to do, in a few lines of code. If you want to do it differently for the sake of your own learning, none of us can suggest what to do).

Comment: i have fixed the 16000x16000 grid to be 16x16, and i dont see how i will ever grow in a this language if I dont understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: oh, and i said no numpy because i considered it

Comment: @pianist1119 You grow by doing stuff that's slightly above what you can do, but still feels like something solvable, and building bit by bit, testing it in the shell as you go. It looks like you've jumped too far above what you can do and are lost. You say you've made it 16x16 but you've actually made it 17x17. `print range(5)` see how it prints five things. Which means you're now trying to fit 257 characters into 289 spaces - so you're still going to run out.

Comment: Sorry I am still new to programming in general, I'm only twelve and I've never had anyone to talk too. This forum is my main source of information. Thank you so much for your help so far and I'll update the post with new range functions, I now understand more how to use the lists of range using zero, and when or when not to increment it past. Both the letter keys and the grid should be in range 16 and 256. I was under the impression I had to add one so my range would actually reach 16, but it doesn't need too. Thanks a load so far though.

Answer (score 1):

The changes needed are: deleting the part shown in comments below and changing the generation of `array_full` to as shown below.

```
class Encryptor():
def __init__(self):
    #array=[]
    #for i in range(129):
    #    array.append(False)
    array_full=[]
    for i in range(129):
        array_full.append()
        for j in range(129):
            array_full[i].append(False)  #edited out: array_full[i] = [False]*129
    self.letterkeys = range(257)
    self.coords=[]
    self.key=False
    self.grid=array_full
```

As has been pointed out by [TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler), when you are updating the value of a cell using `self.grid[coord[0]][coord[1]] = val`, it is updating as well as overwriting previous values of the coordinate that had the index of `coord[1]` in each row. Illustrate that with a simple example of a 3x3 matrix.

```
>>> a = [0]*3
>>> b = []
>>> for i in range(3):
...     b.append(a)
>>> print "\n".join(str(k) for k in b)
[0,0,0]
[0,0,0]
[0,0,0]
>>> b[1][2] = 1
>>> print "\n".join(str(k) for k in b)
[0,0,1]
[0,0,1]
[0,0,1]
```

This will show that changing the value of the element at (1,2) will change the value of the 2nd element in all rows (due the fact that you had generated the matrix using the same copy of `array[]`)

Also, your grid has 129x129 = 16641 cells.
You are updating 257 cells (range(257)).

So, it is pretty obvious that there will be enormous amounts of free space.

Edit: `array_full.append([False]*129)` will run into the same issues described above. You might try using a nested loop as shown (after edit).

Comment: this answer seem to point out an answer for tessalatingheckler's propsal, but for some reason the output code is still simialar

Comment: yes, indeed. i have edited the post. array_full.append([False]*129) will present the same issue as the original post.

Comment: oops i noticed the immense amounts of free space now, so after using your answer to fix duplicates i will try finding a reasonable alternative grid

Comment: alrighty im going to edit my code with your fixes to my understanding but the bug is reoccuring so it still needs work

Comment: looks like i'm a bit stoned, but instead of `array_full[i] = [False]*129`, it would be better to use `array_full[i].append(False)`, although I fail to see how it is any different than what I had originally posted, albeit it was repeating unnecessarily.

Could you elaborate on what you think is the bug? If you think that the number of free space is a bug, then it is due to a lack of keyvalues. You have 257 keys and you are mapping it onto 16641 cells. Obviously, there will be a lot of free space.